# Difference in the change in oxidation states of transition elements and p-block elements

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-trends, oxidation-state

In transition elements the oxidation states differ by one (+2 to +7 in Mn). However, in the p-block elements, the oxidation states differ by two (-1,+1,+3,+5 in the halogen group). Why is this so?

Comment: This is not true of the whole p-block. For example, carbon -1 (ethyne) -2 (ethene) -3 (ethane). It is also not true of the halogens as they can be 0 ($\ce{Cl2}$).

Comment: it's not entirely correct, for example almost all oxidation states from -1 to +7 are known for chlorine. HCl (-1), Cl2 (0), ClF (+1),  ClF3 (+3), ClO2 (+4), ClO2F (+5), ClO3 (+6), HClO4 (+7). All oxidation states from -2 to +6 are known for sulfur. It is more complicated than that.

Comment: But in general isn't it this way? @permeakra

Comment: @IndoUbt Nope. Actually, s/p block typically demonstrates that (covalency+formal charge) usually differs by two except some special cases. This goes to stability of free radicals, which are more stable when the orbital holding unpaired electron is either hidden behind other orbitals (case of 1st d-row), or  is very large (case of neutral nitrogen and chlorine oxides, superoxide anion and so on). This doesn't restrict oxidation state all that much.

Answer (score 0):

In d block, variable valency occurs due to small differences in successive ionization enthalpy. Hence, it shows valency with difference of 1

While in p block, variable valency occurs due to inert pair effect. Due to this 2 electrons remain paired and become inert for bonding. Hence, in p block the difference of 2 occurs.